# using lists in python 3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
number_amount=eval(input("Enter the amount of numbers that will be in the list: "))

for count in range (number_amount):
    l=eval(input("Enter a number for the list: "))
[l]
print ("The smallest number is ", min[l])
print ("The largest number is ", max[l])
print ("The sum is ", sum[l])
print ("The average is ", (sum[l]/number_amount))
```

What I'm trying to do is have the user enter the amount of numbers they want to be in the string, based on the number they input is the amount I need the loop to then ask the user for specific numbers to be in the list.

Then ask for the `min`, `max`, `sun`, and average from their list of numbers.

When I run the program I got this the error:

```
line 6, in <module> print ("The smallest number is ", min(l))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've tried a bunch off different things and am just really lost with what i can do to get the outcome I'm looking for, can anyone help me out? I'd really appreciate it

Comment: I would really recommend not using `eval()` on user input like that. Use `int()` instead. Any arbitrary code entered as input will be executed.

Comment: @IanAuld **Tip:** `json.loads()` can instead `eval()` at every time. But OP really should use `int()` at this time.

Comment: Alternatively, `ast.literal_eval` for generic inputs; it might be useful to allow mixed integer and floating point inputs in certain cases.

Answer (score -1):

```
number_amount=eval(input("Enter the amount of numbers that will be in the list: "))
l  = []
for count in range (number_amount):
   l.append(eval(input("Enter a number for the list: ")))

print ("The smallest number is ", min(l))
print ("The largest number is ", max(l))
print ("The sum is ", sum(l))
print ("The average is ", (sum(l)/number_amount))
```